# European Made fishing rods

Tags: fishing

I am looking for a new fishing rod and reel (combo ideally) but prefer to support non-asian made products. Is there a European manufacturer of fishing rods/reels that doesn't outsource everything to china or asia like everyone does nowadays? Thank you

Comment: http://www.daiwasports.co.uk/product/spectron-match-leger is made in the UK

Comment: saltwater or freshwater rods/reels?

Answer (score 2):

Even if it has a racist note to it I found this:

http://www.thehulltruth.com/sportfishing-charters-forum/200540-any-reels-rods-not-made-china.html#b

Comment: How is it racist especially if he is European and wants to support the economy?

Comment: when you say "he" you mean someone in particular? because when I said "racist note to it" I meant the general feeling in the Q&A session... but hey... that´s my feeling.